# Como copiar los objetos padres desde objetos hijo cuando se recorre el array Java Script

Tags: javascript

De una peticion objengo un array que tiene dos objetos y esos objetos en uno de los elemento hay otro array el cual se requiere que esos elementos de ese array se agreguen en un nuevo array pero que los elementos tengan los elementos padres

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente de la siguiente manera:
Primero agrego el elemento journey a cada objeto del primer array

```
result.forEach(function(item) {

             var data = {"journey":null}
             Object.assign(item, data)

          });
```

Despues recorro el primer array y dentro de ellos recorro los otros array

//se recorre el primer array

```
result.forEach(function(item,index){
            //Creo una variable que contendra el index del primer array   
            var i = index;
            //recorro el segundo array
            item.journeys.forEach(function(it,index){

                //intento que cada elemento del primer array al elemento journey se le agregue los elemento  por recorrido del segundo array
                result[i].journey = it;

                //E irlo agregando al nuevo array
                nuevoarray.push(result[i]);

           /******************************************/
                Aqui es donde no me queda ya que al final si obtengo los 8 elementos pero en el elemento jurney obtengo el ultimo elemento de del segundo ciclo en lugar de que en nuevo array primer elemento dentro de journey tenga el primer elemento del recorrido, el segundo elemento dentro de journey tenga el segundo elemento del segundo ciclo y asi sucesivamente
                   Alguien me pueda ayuda
*/
            });
        });
```

Comment: ¿Podrías revisar el texto? Me cuesta entender el primer párrafo de la pregunta y, por tanto, no entiendo qué quieres obtener. Y lo mismo me pasa con el texto que está en la imagen :(

Comment: Te explico de nuevo tengo un resultado que es  un array ok,  dentro de ese array hay elementos y uno de ellos tambien es un array  se llama "jurneys"  entonces cada objeto del primer array tiene un elemento llamado "journesy" que es un array que tiene 4 elementos

Comment: entonce  lo que se pretende es recorrer los journeys para crear un nuevo array que tendra los objetos padre,  y se añadera un nuevo elemento llamado jurney que cuando se recorren los elementos jurneys se iran añadiendo a jurney  entonces tendre en este ejemplo  cada elemento jurneys tinene 4 elementos entonces seran 8 elementos que seran los objetos padre y dentro de ellos el elemento jurney que tendra indepentientemente el elemento que se fue recorriendo en los elementos journeys

Comment: Deberías: A. completar el [tour] B. [edit] la pregunta y arreglarla, en lugar de poner aclaraciones como comentarios

Comment: var x = { objeto1, objeto2}
objeto1 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3 }
elemento3 = {elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4}

Comment: Muestro otro ejemplo haber si me explico

result = { objeto1, objeto2}

objeto1 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3 }
elemento3 = {elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4}

objeto2 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3 }
elemento3 = {elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4}

entonces lo que se requiere es:
un nuevo array que seras asi
nuevoarray =  { objeto1, objeto2, objeto3, objeto4, objeto5, objeto6, objeto7, objeto8}

Comment: Los primeros 4 pertecen al primer objeto de result
objeto1 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3, elemento4:elem1 }
objeto2 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3, elemento4:elem2 }
objeto3 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3, elemento4:elem3 }
objeto4 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3, elemento4:elem4 }

Losotros 4 pertecen al segundo objeto de result
objeto5 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3, elemento4:elem1 }
objeto6 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3, elemento4:elem2 }
objeto7 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3, elemento4:elem3 }
objeto8 = {elemento1,elemento2,elemento3, elemento4:elem4 }

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/juvesys/dux3w247/45/  Aqui te muestro un ejmplo

veras la consola y veras 8 objetos  y dentro de ellos veras un elemento llamado jurney la cual por cada elemento debe tener un objeto el primero deberia ser xa, el segundo xb hasta llegar al xd, luego el  5 objeto en su elemento jurney deberias empezas ya el 6to yb y asi pero en los primero cuatro se repite xa y en los otros cuatro se remite ya

Comment: Has leído mi comentario anterior? Edita la pregunta y añade todo ahí, no lo pongas como comentarios